# Windows - Find recently moved files

Tags: windows, windows-10

I was trying to move files from my phone to the PC, and can't remember the location of the files now. Is there any way in Windows (10) to find this? I tried with file explorer and then using Windows Search to find the recently modified files in my computer but it takes forever, even when I narrowed it down to pictures and date modified "today".

Are there some other options, like looking through logs, or using some other software / scripting?

The files certainly dissapeared from the phone, and I can't find them in the recycle bin, so my guess is they were moved successfully

The steps I rember doing: creating some new folder, cutting files from the phone, going to that folder and pasting them

Comment: (1) You can narrow the search to USERS and that should go faster.  (2) Take an arbitrary file you can delete, cut it, paste it and slow down here and see where the recent paste is going.

Comment: (1) - you mean to the "users" folder?
(2) - I don't understand, can you elaborate please?

Comment: Look down your main folder tree.  USERS has all the user profiles including profile contents (documents and so on). You can search that.

Comment: Re (2) I am asking you to cut a file and then look when you paste it to see where it is going to be pasted. If nothing has changed, that could lead you to your files.

Comment: (1) if by this folder you meant for example: C:\Users, then I found nothing in there unfortunatelly
(2) if I cut the file and just paste it then it's gonna get get pasted to whatever folder I have opened currently or whichever is marked in the explorer, so how would that help? Am I missing something here?

Comment: "so my guess is they were moved successfully" - times I have seen this go wrong are numerous.

Comment: If you cannot find the files in your User folder and cannot replicate the move, then you probably need to set up a search of your C: drive and let it run overnight.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is my goto tool for this type of tasks.

https://www.voidtools.com/

Select drive to which you moved files > apply sort, by date, date accessed or whatever you need.

[image]

Comment: seems to not work. found only 7k files with .jpg extension and only few of them are with the modification date around the time when I did the copying. those are not those files

Comment: I answered your 'sort by date modified' question. Your complaint was that it took too long using built in tools. In my experience Everything tends to be faster.

Comment: what do you mean? I didn't ask how to sort by date modified, but how to find those files:D

Comment: with all due respect

Comment: the way it's phrased to me suggests you tried locate files by modified date but were unsuccessful using built-in windows tools.

Comment: now I see, sorry. Yes it's faster, but this doesn't find the files :( Also weird it only found like 7k files :/

Comment: and they were jpegs? but you do not know any full names?